# Combine Leaflet with Geoserver WMS map

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet

I'm not very skilled within the GIS world, however, I would like to know if it's possible to use this map:

http://wfs-kbhkort.kk.dk/k101/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=k101:theme-startkort&styles=&bbox=12.451709828167994,55.63150896601625,12.64714535243575,55.72503797474024&width=512&height=495&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

within leaflet?

I've looked at the API for leaflet and can see that it is possible to use custom maps/tiles with the tileLayer option. However, I cannot get it to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at [L.tilelayer.wms](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-wms) in the API.

In your case you should get something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([55.67, 12.60], 11);

var mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://wfs-kbhkort.kk.dk/k101/wms", {
    layers: 'k101:theme-startkort',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "myattribution"
});
mywms.addTo(map);
```