# Web map viewer for QGIS Server and PostGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, web-mapping, qgis-server

I have succesfully installed and configured QGIS Server. I tried WMS and WFS via QGIS Desktop and it works perfectly.

Now i am looking for a web map viewer to display (only read (WMS viewer i guess)) the layers being served in QGIS Server. I tried qgis2leaf which generates a leaflet html with a qgis project layers. Quite powerful. I tried also a similar plugin that exports the layers to a openlayers html file.

The problem is that what this does is to EXPORT the data in the layers in the QGIS project to JSON files that are read in the generated html file.

In my particular case, i am using a postgis database and layers' information may change as other users edit it. I want to avoid to regenerate the html files every night or whensoever (I can have 20 or more maps) so that the data is exported again and people can see the changes on the web map viewer. I just want to export the project once and the data of the layers stay linked to the postgis tables.

Is there a good free web map viewer that respects this condition?

Comment: Use OpenLayers or Leaflet to consume your QGIS Server WMS service, e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73967/combine-leaflet-with-geoserver-wms-map

Comment: In that case i would have to modify the generated website by myself in every project i try to export. I believe i also would need a backend (node.js i.e) to serve the data to the frontend. I am trying to avoid all of this with a software that i am sure it already exists.

Comment: QGIS Server IS the backend.

Comment: Yes my fault, you are right. I still would have to modify every website i generate.

Comment: You have to set up the web viewer for all the WMS layers you want to use - of course. Maybe QGIS Web Client is for you, maybe you want something custom, there's not enough information in the question to tell.

Comment: qgis2leaf can retain the layers as remote WFS/WMS - it doesn't have to encode them to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have allready installed a working Qgis Server, then you should examine if Lizmap webclient could accomodate your needs (has a lizmap qgis plugin to specify webmap-properties of each layer). Pretty easy way to specify popups etc. 
Features: http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/lizmapwebclient/Features_en
Pretty easy to install on existing osgeo4w apache. (windows 2008 server in my case)