# Publish a Leaflet map with vector overlay on a WMS server (e.g. GeoServer)

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet, mapproxy

Is it possible to set up a WMS server (I am a bit familiar with `GeoServer` so this would be my preferred option but of course I'm open to learn something new...) that publishes an instance of a Leaflet map together with some vector overlays (e.g. GeoJSON, shapefile, whatever..)? Or am I mixing up things completely here because maps created in JavaScript cannot be published like this?

This would be nice to have for my usecase as I have set up a nice map with Leaflet which receives map tiles from our company's own tile server, does some styling, uses Leaflet plugins to display interesting stuff etc.

I would like to do some automated `GetMap requests` on that map for bounding box extents that I generate programmatically and save the resulting images to disk.

The closest I could think of would be to use [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) to combine my custom tile layer with my vector overlays (directly or prepared by and connected through GeoServer) and publish that as a WMS server. However, this would lack the styling and plugin stuff that I can do in Leaflet.

Comment: What do you want as an end-result?

Comment: The end result would be a WMS Server which responds to GetMap requests by providing a static image made of a Leaflet map combined with some vector overlays.

Comment: Well Leaflet doesn't do that. You can do it with GeoServer, though. Do all your styling with GeoServer and then you can display it with Leaflet or just run a getmap request and get a static image. Leaflet is for making a slippy map, not an image. Also, you can install a plugin for GeoServer that sets up PDF output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up a couple of things.

When you install Geoserver, it comes with a lite distribution of OpenLayers. That is used to preview the data once you publish some. But this functionality is only suitable for previewing, and not as a production front-end.

If you want a Production quality front end, you need to develop that yourself. You can use any client which supports Geoserver's OGC Services( i.e. WMS, WFS etc).

Many people use OpenLayers as a JavaScript Library for this, or you could also use Leaflet.

There are many examples on this site which talk about doing so, for example: [Combine Leaflet with Geoserver WMS map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73967/combine-leaflet-with-geoserver-wms-map)

If your Geoserver or data cannot be projected in Web Mercator, then you can us a Leaflet plugin called [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet), which can display a Map in projections other than Web Mercator. See this [example](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/tree/master/examples/wms).

Comment: Okay, thanks. If I could live without the special Leaflet features and just want to publish a map being composed of a basemap from a tile server in the form of `https://myserver.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` and some vector overlays such that the end result can be received as a static image by a `GetMap` request - is this what I need then? http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/index.html

I already tried to do something similar with a combination of `GeoServer` and `MapProxy` but it was very hard to set it up properly.

Comment: If you have a Map service in Z/x/y format, why don't you use that directly? why do you need to make a getMap request? Am I missing something?