# Display a map using leaflet API

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

I have a geoserver installed on my local machine and on it i have published the map which is connected to Postegresql.

Now i can view a map on geoserver using the openlayers viewer (url-"http://localhost:8081/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test:city_limit&styles=&bbox=-114.315796136219,50.842822033593,-113.859905274451,51.2124253170889&width=768&height=622&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers")"

Now i have code api of leaflet to customise a map which is hosted on geoserver.

Here is a HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html >
<head >
    <title> Leaflet Demo </title>


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
   <script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" >
    <div id="map"></div>

    <div>

    var map = L.map('map').setView([55.67, 12.60], 11);

    var mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8081/geoserver/test/wms", {
    layers: 'k101:theme-startkort',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "myattribution"
    });
    mywms.addTo(map);
     </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when compiling on visual studio ,browser displays :
a code itself

Any idea, what to do?

Comment: have you tried that html code on a a browser without going through visual studio ?

Comment: yes sir ...........

Comment: in both cases browser displays nothing

Comment: you say that you can display your WMS layer in openlayers but the url you provided shows another one (test:city_limit) not the one on your code 'k101:theme-startkort', maybe the problem comes from there, check if this layer is valid

Comment: http://localhost:8081/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test:city_limit&styles=&bbox=-114.315796136219,50.842822033593,-113.859905274451,51.2124253170889&width=768&height=622&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

Comment: above is the link of geoserver in which i can see my map through openlayers........

Comment: as i am begineers to gis .........so i dont know much about it

Comment: please specify what has to be written in L.titlelayer.wms parameters

Comment: Can you display the layer you are using in your code 'k101:theme-startkort in the same way you tested test:city_limit ? I modified your url http://localhost:8081/geoserver/test/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=test:city_limit&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers  (copy it and paste it on your browser )

Comment: var mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8081/geoserver/test/wms", {
    layers: 'test:city_limit',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "myattribution"
    });
    mywms.addTo(map);

Comment: i was doing wrong .....now i have modified layer to 'test:city_limit'

Comment: anything else has to be change??

Comment: code should be in a script not a div element

Comment: oo sorry .......let make a change..

Comment: sir  i have changed........but same problem.....browser displays nothing

Comment: i am waiting sir for your reply

Comment: sir earlier i used the same procedure as on link "http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73967/combine-leaflet-with-geoserver-wms-map?rq=1"    but that doesn't solved my problem ...so  i posted a new question

Comment: please sir try to resolve my problem......

Comment: anyone please check for the errors .......i am badly stuck with connectivity due to which i am not able to proceed my project