# How to add a OneGeology Layer to a Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, wms, geology

My question is a continuation of [Combine Leaflet with Geoserver WMS map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73967) (asked by someone else. I also understand the JavaScript in that post - my Q is not about javascript or leaflet).

However I tried to include *geological* map layers .

What I envision is: A user "drills down" from a topographic world map to a specific location, and *then*, after a click, optionally gets a geological map of a ~ 10*10 km² area. (I do not need to display a geological map of the  entire world)

The codesample I've linked to gives a head start but I do not know how to

- find a suitable description on how to get a list of WMS Services curated/aggregated by Onegeology.org, (and optionally -if there are API restrictions- how to write Leaaflet.js code for it)
- or alternatively get a Link to a different website that offers similar datasets/endpoints but better curated than by Onegeology.org (it does not have to be Onegeology.org - but according to my knowledge this seems to be the largest coordinated effort to-date to provide free geology data)

I've searched the OneGeology website but I did not find anything useful except some screenshot-walkthroughs to embed UK-specific WMS links into GUI-based GIS Software.

If there are other providers of geology data who offer geological maps as Leaflet-embeddable layers for any point of the Earth, I'll happily take that datasource instead. For example, I like this way to showcase layers and overlays:  ["Leaflet Provider demo"](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html)  for topographic maps. Is there something similar for geology layers?

Comment: OneGeology.org is **not** a provider of data, OneGeology portal showcases WMS/WCS services by distributed providers (and provides access to WFS services).  Such services follow standard protocols so you don't (or shouldn't) need to be concerned about whether the service is coming from MapServer, GeoServer, or ArcGIS/ArcIMS or other servers (all apply).  You have found the information on how to get the service URL for any (single) map layer, so you just need to find all the map layers you want to show in your application and use standard Leaflet techniques for adding WMS/WCS/WFS as applicable.

Comment: Note the target scale for all map layers shown in the OneGeology portal is 1:1,000,000.  Service providers (in the main geological survey organizations)  aim to provide maps from their collections at a scale as close as possible to this scale.  There isn't global geology available at several scales so you won't be able to zoom in and change information.

Comment: The list of services (map layers) registered in the portal can be found through the OneGeology catalogue (http://onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr/geonetwork3/srv/eng/catalog.search#/home), please be aware that not all listed services are currently available.    _Disclaimer: I am actively involved in the OneGeology project._

Comment: I've solved the problem myself, this is the result: https://www.icdp-online.org/fileadmin/icdp/maps/interactive/proj_icdp_acronym_interactive_world.html

Comment: I am now using http://mapsref.brgm.fr/wxs/1GG/CGMW_Bedrock_and_Structural_Geology?&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities - it serves OneGeology data (specifically the layer labeled ONEGEOLOGY_CGM "CGMW Bedrock and structural geology of the World" ) from a mapserver in France.  I also use USGS World geology data described in in https://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/ofr20051294?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.3.0